# Best practice for Ajax, Rails and UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have a basic Rails application using Ajax (I followed this great [Railscast tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised))

On creating new records, it does an ajax call, using :remote => true, so the flow is:

**User clicks submit > Ajax call > New record created > UI updated with new record**

This all works fine, however there is a (very) small wait between the user hitting submit and the record being added. Only noticeable if a lot of users on hitting it. What I would prefer to do is:

**User clicks submit > UI updated with new record (with throbber) > Ajax call > New record created > Throbber removed on success**

So for the user the submission is instant, no wait, even though the record is still being created on the back end.

I'm wondering is there a best practice for doing this in Rails? Or is it just a matter of writing some custom javascript to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `:remote => true` rails uses `jquery_ujs` to submit the ajax requests. The UJS library provides callbacks to hook in custom code at various points.

What you need is something like this:

```
$('form.new_record').on('ajax:beforeSend', function(event, xhr, settings) {
    // Show throbber
    return true;
});
```

See this link for more details: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is the best thing but instead of immediately creating a record in UI you should show the throbber till you get the response from server that the object has been created successfully. You should also handle any validation errors in case there are any and show it on the client.